# Purpose of passing CSS class name more than once in one element

Tags: css

we pass CSS class name in an element to apply that class on that element but what is purpose of passing CSS class name more then once in one element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By combining two or more classes on one element, it allows you to write less CSS. Here's a simplified [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sHBaT/):

```
<p class="error message small">Error!</p>
<p class="success message">Success!</p>
```

```
.message {
     margin:0 0 1em;
     position:relative;
     padding:1em;
     border-radius:4px;
 }
 .small {
     font-size:80%;
    padding:.5em;
 }
 .error {
     background-color:#FBE3E4;
     color:#8a1f11;
 }
 .success {
     background-color:#dfffe5;
     color:#264409;
 }
```

With this, we can still use each class independently, or combine them with any other combination of class names to inherit the style declarations of each.

If you meant using the *same* class name repeatedly on one element, then there is no purpose.

Comment: accepted due to code example and working example.

Answer (score 3):

There is no purpose for doing this. AFAIK this has the same effect as placing the class only once on the element.

Answer (score 2):

Im assuming you mean 2 different classes? As chkal mentioned doing the same class twice would be no different then doing it once.

Multiple classes can also make it easier to add special effects to elements without having to create a whole new style for that element. For example, you may want to have the ability to float elements to the left or right quickly. You might write two classes "left" and "right" with just "float:left;" and "float:right;" in them. Then whenever you had an element you need to float left you would simply add the class "left" to its class list.

Source: http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/qt/tipcssmulticlas.htm

Comment: Yesterday I saw this one: `.menu_left { float:right; }`... I know I used "small" in my example, but thought I'd mention for OP that it's best to use class names that describe what the content *is* in some way, not what you want it to *look like*, otherwise you can end up with stuff like `.red-text {color:blue;}` when you decide to make a style change, but can't be bothered to fix the class name in a hundred HTML templates.